# Subir multiples imagenes a un S3 usando nextjs

Tags: aws, fileupload, nextjs, amazon-s3

Estoy creando un ecommerce con nextjs 13.3.1 y quiero subir múltiples imágenes de un producto a un s3,cuál es la forma de hacerlo?

Comment: que has intentado?

Comment: Hola Jonas, bienvenido, para poder ayudarte, necesitamos ver tu código y los mensajes de error (si es que los recibes) en formato texto, y que nos expliques en que falla, mira Cómo preguntar para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.